# What is __CUDANVVM__ for?

Tags: cuda

The macros `__CUDACC__`, `__CUDANVVM__`, and `__CUDA_ARCH__` are used in many places in the CUDA library header files. I am able to find info on `__CUDACC__` and `__CUDA_ARCH__`, but I don't get anything on Google regarding `__CUDANVVM__` other than finding it used in the headers. Due to the usage for static/forced-inline of calls through to functions of the form `__nv_<base_function_name>`, my intuition is that it is used as part of the process of compiling with `libdevice` and those `__nv_*` functions are the device-optimized bitcode versions of the functions they correspond to, but I'm not yet sure and so was looking for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/libdevice-users-guide/function-desc.html#function-desc, it appears that the `__nv_*` functions are indeed those from `libdevice`, so it seems my hunch was correct.

Comment: If you could accept your own answer, this question will drop off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag

Comment: I was actually planning to once the wait period expired but forgot to do so. Thanks for reminding me.